# Unable to parse "CET" from formatted DateString

Tags: flutter, dart

Why the `DateFormat` Parser cant parse CET?

```
final String dateString = "Sat Jul 05 00:00:00 CET 1975";
final DateTime dateTime =
    DateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss vvv yyyy").parse(dateString);
```

Results in

> FormatException: Trying to read   from Sat Jul 05 00:00:00 CET 1975 at position 21

Position 21 would be "C" if I count right.

Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: please note: instead of "vvv" I also tried "zzz" and "ZZZ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intl` package didn't implement parsing time zones yet, as evident in [`date_format_field`](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/src/intl/date_format_field.dart) class :

```
      case 'v':
        return formatTimeZoneId(date);
      case 'z':
        return formatTimeZone(date);
      case 'Z':
        return formatTimeZoneRFC(date);
```

And when you look at these functions implementation :

```
  String formatTimeZoneId(DateTime date) {
    // TODO(alanknight): implement time zone support
    throw new UnimplementedError();
  }

  String formatTimeZone(DateTime date) {
    throw new UnimplementedError();
  }

  String formatTimeZoneRFC(DateTime date) {
    throw new UnimplementedError();
  }
```

This [`issue`](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/74) has been open since 2015, and this is the response of one of the people responsible for it :

> We don't expect to implement those until Dart DateTime's have time zone information, and that's not planned. I wouldn't expect it unless/until JavaScript DateTime's have them. Including localized TimeZone names is a lot of data. We should probably just remove those APIs until such time as we actually provide them.